# Getting an error "Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am getting the following error while running this application i have specified the URL and JDBC driver properly and place the derbyclient.jar inside the /lin folder of tomcat

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at DbServlet.processRequest(DbServlet.java:45)
at DbServlet.doGet(DbServlet.java:79)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:524)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:493)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:273)
at              org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:14    37)
... 26 more
```

this is context.xml code for web-app under META-INF folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/DataSrcWeb2">
<resource driverClass="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" name="myData"      type="javax.sql.Datasource"
url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myData" username="niit" password="password"/>
```

This is my web.xml file. JDBC driver and URl are all right.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DbServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>DbServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>DbServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DbServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<resource-ref>
<description>Connection Pool</description>
<res-ref-name>myData</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: In your context.xml driverClass should be driverClassName

Comment: Well have tried with driverClassName, was the same issue

Comment: If you remove the <resource> tag from your context.xml, does the crash go away? If so, that's an indication that the Tomcat data source processing is mis-understanding your <resource> tag. You're not getting to the actual Derby driver; you're crashing in some odbc code, so it looks like the xml configuration files are confusing the Tomcat engine.